# Do I need to install after boot up from USB

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have successfully copied Ubuntu 18.04 onto a USB flash drive and boot it up on my laptop. There is an icon that said "install Ubuntu", do I need to click that icon and install Ubuntu onto my USB drive?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu onto a flash drive, however whether or not you've already done this or not is unclear. My guess is from your description, you're running it in 'live' mode (ie. *Try Ubuntu*" which means any changes you make, or files stored to your current file-system get erased on shutdown/reboot. This is a positive (you can test or try things out, and it's fixed by a reboot) but also a problem if you forget this (unless you save to a real file-system). It's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the install button, it will install Ubuntu to the hard disk of your machine.

You do not have to install it, however. You can run the Ubuntu operating system in Live Mode directly from the USB to decide if you are comfortable with it, but any changes you make will not be saved between restarts.

If you do decide you like the Ubuntu Linux operating system, you can install it -- either as a dual boot alongside an existing Windows install or by overwriting the Windows operating system entirely. It is all up to how you want to use it.

Welcome to the world of Ubuntu!